# How to use (AuthenTec) biometrics to directly unlock Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fingerprint, biometrics

When my computer returns from sleep/lock it presents a logon screen where I can enter my password. To use biometrics, I must first press two buttons: "Other credentials" followed by the "Fingerprint unlock" for my user account.

How can I skip those two screens (and button presses)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind... I found the answer while asking, but I am posting the answer for others:

**It is possible to use the fingerprint reader on any of those logon screens (without pressing a single button.)**

Is this well-designed because this is possible, or not well-designed because the ability to do so is not obvious?